# Get Post ID within wp_set_comment_status hook

Tags: comments, post-meta

I am trying to update `meta_value` whenever I manually approve a comment inside the WordPress dashboard. I could not figure out how to do it dynamically, but it is working when I manually add a post ID:

```
add_action( 'wp_set_comment_status', 'average_ratings', 10, 2 );
function average_ratings( $comment_ID, $comment_status ) {
    if ( $comment_status == 'approve' ) {
        function average_ratingfn() {
            global $wpdb;

            $post_id = '208';  

            // bla bla bla
        }
        $commentar = average_ratingfn();
        add_post_meta( '208', 'overall', $commentar );   
    }
}
```

How can I replace `208` with `get_the_ID()`?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider removing the `average_ratingfn()` function definition out of there and call it with an input argument for the post ID.

You can try to fetch the comment object with (untested):

```
$comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
```

and then make sure it's not null or you have an actual comment object with:

```
if( $comment instanceof \WP_Comment )
    $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
```

You should be able to get the `comment_post_ID` field from that object.

I think you could also use the hooks within the `wp_transition_comment_status()` function, where the comment object is among the input arguments.

For example the hooks:

- `comment_{$new_status}_{$comment->comment_type}`
- `comment_{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}`
- `transition_comment_status`